# Run different grunt tasks based on filenames

Tags: gruntjs

I have a folder with prefixed images, which I want to resize based on their type (header, preview, article. Initially all images have the same size.

```
images/
    header_a.jpg
    header_b.jpg
    preview_a.jpg
    preview_b.jpg
    article_a.jpg
    article_b.jpg
```

Now I'd like to resize the images:

- header images to 1280px width
- article images to 640px width
- preview images to 200px width

Right now I'm using [grunt-responsive-images](https://github.com/andismith/grunt-responsive-images) to resize the images, but this only resizes all images to the same format(s).

What could I do? This is how my Gruntfile looks right now:

```
grunt.initConfig({

    responsive_images: {

        resize: {
            options: {
                sizes: [{
                    width: 640,
                }]
            },

            files: [{
                expand: true,
                src: ['**.{jpg,gif,png}'],
                cwd: 'app/in/',
                custom_dest: 'app/out/'
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
responsive_images: {

    resize_header: {
        options: {
            sizes: [{ width: 1280 }]
        },
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            src: ['**/header*.{jpg,gif,png}'],
            cwd: 'app/in/',
            custom_dest: 'app/out/'
        }]
    },
    resize_article: {
        options: {
            sizes: [{ width: 640 }]
        },
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            src: ['**/article*.{jpg,gif,png}'],
            cwd: 'app/in/',
            custom_dest: 'app/out/'
        }]
    },
    resize_preview: {
        options: {
            sizes: [{ width: 200 }]
        },
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            src: ['**/preview*.{jpg,gif,png}'],
            cwd: 'app/in/',
            custom_dest: 'app/out/'
        }]
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I run different tasks based on different folders:

```
responsive_images: {
    image_type_1: {
        options: {
            sizes: [{
                    width: 1680
            }, {
                    width: 450
            }]
        },
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            src: ['**.{jpg,gif,png}'],
            cwd: 'source/img/temp/responsive_images/image_type_1/',
            dest: 'source/img/temp/responsive_images_output/'
        }]
    },
    image_type_2: {
        options: {
            sizes: [{
                    width: 600,
                    height: 340,
                    aspectRatio: false
            }, {
                    width: 210,
                    height: 280,
                    aspectRatio: false
            }]
        },
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            src: ['**.{jpg,gif,png}'],
            cwd: 'source/img/temp/responsive_images/image_type_2/',
            dest: 'source/img/temp/responsive_images_output/'
        }]
    }
}
```

Instead of different folders, you could probably match the filenames in the src-path (don't exactly know how to do this). But as you can only define one sizes-array per task, you definitely have to write a task for each image type.